# MVC Windows Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC in Windows Forms. I have a question regarding wizards/dialogs/error_msgs in MVC that is where should I call the wizards/dialogs/error_msgs

i. show from controller
ii. notify the view from controller to show dialogs/wizards/error_msg

Which approach is correct?

```
    class Controller
{
    IView view;

    public void DoSomthing() 
    {
        // i) approach

        Wizard wz = new Wizard();
        wz.Show();

        MessageBox.Show("Error while DoSomething");


        // ii) approach

        view.ShowWizard();

        view.ShowErrorBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "wizards/dialogs/error_msgs" means and what the Wizard class is. Not knowing what it is, we have no idea when it should be called.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Dialog can be FileOpen Dialog which will be shown to user on button click, and if there is any error doing operation in controller then we can show errorbox to user so what i am asking is where should i write code for these two scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with @StealthRabbi's comment, you should be more specific, and explain what is `wizards/dialogs/erros_msgs`, from your code I assume, you want to know, whether you should directly create and show `Wizard` window from `controller` or ask `view` to show it.
Clearly the answer is `ii)` option, all UI related stuff should be done by `view`. Showing `Wizard` window is UI related stuff, so `controller` shouldn't directly create `Wizard`, but rather ask `view` to do that. So your code should go like this

```
class Controller
{
    IView view;

    public void DoSomthing() 
    {
        // ii) approach

        view.ShowWizard();

        view.ShowErrorBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer and your assumtion was right about my question :)